# Задача 'Кинотеатр'. Помогите с оптимизацией пожалуйста

Tags: python, python-3.x, оптимизация, инспекция-кода

> Марья Ивановна с Марьей Михайловной привели школьников в кинотеатр. Чтобы не было никаких обид, Марья Ивановна построила всех школьников по алфавиту и рассадила их: сначала в первый ряд слева направо, затем во второй слева направо и так далее, заполнив весь зал из n рядов по m кресел. Тут пришла Марья Михайловна и сказала, что ребята сели неправильно — надо пересесть. Она предложила сначала заполнить все первые места от первого ряда к последнему, затем все вторые места и так далее.
> Определите, сколько школьников после такой пересадки останется на своем месте.
> Например, если n=3 и m=3, то в первом случае дети сядут так:
>
> 1 2 3
> 4 5 6
> 7 8 9
>
> Во втором же случае дети сядут так:
>
> 1 4 7
> 2 5 8
> 3 6 9
>
> Таким образом, три школьника: 1, 5 и 9 останутся на своих местах.

Мой код:

```py
from itertools import count as count_from
a,b=map(int,input().split())
count_1=0
count = count_from(1)
matrix = [[next(count) for _ in range(a)] for _ in range(b)]
matrix1 = [[0 for j in range(a)] for i in range(b)]
count = count_from(1)
for l in range(a):
    for h in range(b):
        matrix1[h][l]=next(count)
for k in range(a):
    for g in range(b):
        if matrix[g][k]==matrix1[g][k]:
            count_1+=1
print(count_1)
```

Но он выполняется слишком долго. Помогите пожалуйста оптимизировать его.

Comment: задача наверняка решается аналитически. Т.е. не перебором всех клеток, а вычислением одной формулы.

Comment: @Эникейщик Если считать задачу реальной, то даже перебор довольно быстр. Для миллиона учеников (согласитесь - это очень большая школа и кинозал :) ) перебор занимает менее 2 секунд.

Comment: А вот множество проходов делать не обязательно. Всё можно определить за один проход.

Comment: @T_Darp Вы не приняли ни один из ответов на ваши вопросы. Если все ответы непонятны, то зачем продолжать?

Comment: Был тест на 
3 1000000000
Времени дают 2 секунды, но этого не хватило для программы.

Comment: Вообще остаётся на месте только диагональ, и именно это я и заметил. Я пропобовал вычислить гипотенузу, но это это не работало.

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю есть ли для такой задачи формула, но перебором это однозначно делается за за один "проход":

```
n = int(input("Рядов? "))
m = int(input("Кресел в ряду? "))
c = len([1 for ni in range(n) for mi in range(m) if ni*m+mi == mi*n+ni])
print(c)
```